# Dimension of the cartesian product of a poset and a chain

Tags: posets

Let $P$ be a finite poset and for $n\in\mathbb N$, let $\bf n$ denote the $n$-element totally ordered set.

If $m,n\in\mathbb N$ and $1<m<n$, is the dimension of $P\times \bf m$ equal to the dimension of $P\times\bf n$?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "dimension".

Comment: The smallest number of totally ordered sets such that a poset can be order-embedded into a product of those totally ordered sets. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_dimension

Comment: Tri, "product" or "intersection"?

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be the dimension of $P$.
This means that $P$ can be embedded into a direct product of $k$ chains, but it cannot be embedded into a direct product of less than $k$ chains.

Now if $$ P \hookrightarrow C_1 \times \dots \times C_k $$
then of course  $$ P \times \mathbf{n} \hookrightarrow C_1 \times \dots \times C_k \times \mathbf{n} $$
which shows that the dimension of $ P \times \mathbf{n} $ is at most $k+1$.
On the other hand, it is also clear the dimension of $P$ is less than or equal than the dimension of $P \times \mathbf{n}$.

So the only possible values for the dimension of a product of $P$ and a finite chain are either $k$ or $k+1$. We can infer that for infinitely many values of
$m$ and $n$ indeed the dimensions of $P \times \mathbf{n}$ and $P \times \mathbf{m}$ will be the same. I conjecture that they will all be equal to $k+1$ and thus equal to each other; but I cannot as yet prove or disprove it.